# CallbackError with OmniAuth When Proxying Through Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, nginx, proxy, omniauth

So I'm using OmniAuth with the GitHub strategy to handle user authentication for my project. When accessing the Rails server directly, everything works as it should. I recently set up Nginx to handle proxying between my development frontend and backend servers. Now when I visit `/auth/github`, OmniAuth fires off the request to GitHub, but then fails on the callback with:

```
Started GET "/auth/github/callback?error=redirect_uri_mismatch" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 11:54:35 -0800
I, [2014-01-22T11:54:35.365773 #13656]  INFO -- omniauth: (github) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2014-01-22T11:54:35.366091 #13656] ERROR -- omniauth: (github) Authentication failure! redirect_uri_mismatch: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, redirect_uri_mismatch
E, [2014-01-22T11:54:35.366149 #13656] ERROR -- omniauth: (github) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, redirect_uri_mismatch
```

I have set the callback URL in my application's settings on GitHub to the correct URL and it's obviously making the request properly, just with this mysterious `redirect_uri_mismatch`.

Here's my Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

I can't really see any good reason why this shouldn't be working, though I am a relative noob to configuring Nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the issue here was that I wasn't setting my headers properly. Adding the following to my location blocks in my Nginx config fixed this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG, it took me a month to fix this.
I constantly were getting - `No route matches [GET] /auth/facebook`

**Nginx conf**

```
location @rails {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }
```

**Gemfile**

```
#auth
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 8.0'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9.1' #this is important
```

**application.rb**

```
config.force_ssl = ENV['CLIENT_URL'].include?("https")
```

**omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],
          scope: 'email',
          callback_path: '/api/v1/auth/facebook/callback',
          image_size: 'large',
          secure_image_url: true,
          display: 'touch'
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what *CLIENT_URL* is meant to be but setting `config.force_ssl = true` did the trick for google oauth2.

Comment: That's the way to detect https. CLIENT_URL is a redirect domain.

Comment: can u share ur full nginx config?

Comment: @buncis https://pastebin.com/Dz7wzrwm you need to change [host]

Comment: @TimKozak hat app server did you use? puma?

Comment: @buncis yes it was puma. let me know